How to enforce MATPOWERs runpf to keep the flow limits?
In Matlab, I have given a network in the MATPOWER case file format (see the MATPOWER doc).
I now want to check, if it is AC-feasible. To that end, I employed runpf (see the MATPOWER doc):
define_constants;
mpc = loadcase(case_file_path);
results = runpf($mpc);

On most of my cases, I got the result that it is feasible. Now I wanted to check the branch violations of the infeasible ones. However, I noticed that there are also branch violations on the ones that are marked as feasible (which for me does not make sense from a physical POV).
I calculated the violations as follows:
pfs = results.branch(:, PF);
qfs = results.branch(:, QF);
pts = results.branch(:, PT);
qts = results.branch(:, QT);
Sfs = sqrt(pfs.^2 + qfs.^2);
Sts = sqrt(pts.^2 + qts.^2);
active = mpc_target.branch(:, 11) > 0.5;
rates = mpc_target.branch(:, 6); % the 6th column gives the rateA of the branch 
violations_n = sum((Sfs .* active > rates) | (Sts .* active > rates));

My guess is that the function does not enforce the limits in the network, but that is what I need.
What I tried so far:
In the description of runpf it is mentioned, that the pf.enforce_q_lims option exists. I tried to set it to true (in the hope that this will somehow lead to an adherence of the flow limits as well), but the result remained unchanged.
I found another function runcpf. This function DOES have the option cpf.enforce_flow_lims. However, the function seems to perform a continuation power flow, which I am guessing is not what I want since I need a base case and a target case (I am not an electrical engineer, so I have limited knowledge). Nevertheless, I ran the function (with both cases being the base case and the aforementioned option activated), but the result remained the same: the same violations occurr.
I am unsure how to proceed. Is this simply not possible with MATPOWER due to restriction I am not aware of? This seems impractical to me however.

The behavior you're observing is actually expected - runpf performs a power flow calculation to determine if a solution exists that satisfies Kirchhoff's laws and the specified power injections/demands, but it does not enforce branch flow limits by default. This is because branch flow limits are typically considered as operational constraints rather than physical laws.
If you need to find a solution that respects branch flow limits, I would recommend you to use MATPOWER's OPF functionality instead. The OPF will try to find a solution that satisfies power flow equations, respect branch flow limits, keep voltages within bounds, respect generator limits and minimize generation cost.
You can read more about it here: https://matpower.org/docs/ref/matpower5.0/opf.html

As I understand it, in this function the power generation of the generators is not fixed. But I want to pass a fixed power generation and see, if there's a power flow possible (adhering to the branch limits) with the given settings. Is Matpower not able to do that?

This is actually a limitation of MATPOWER. The standard power flow (runpf) can handle fixed generation but doesn't enforce branch limits, while OPF (runopf) enforces branch limits but allows generation to vary.
You could try to approximate using runopf with very tight generator limits, this usually worked in my cases when I had to do analysis. Tho, you may have convergence issues due to the very tight constraints and it might still allow tiny variations in generator output, depending on the values you use.

Hence if I do runopf and it returns infeasible, it cannot obtain an opf with the given branch limits (and equally for runpf with the given generator settings), correct?
I am still a little confused, bc I still get violations on the branches when running opf and MATPOWER returns "feasible". Also, when running opf, one generator changes its values (always exactly one, which is weird)?
Also, by "running opf with tight generator limits" you mean that I should set Pmax and Pmin to similar values than my desired pg, correct? I still end up with the same gen changes. Is there something I oversaw?
